# C# MongoDB : Chunk file does not upload following a prior deletion

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having a bit of a problem with an update feature designed to compare two images, and if different, delete the existing image and data from Mongo, and replace it with a new copy. The problem is, individually, each component works. The loading feature will successfully upload an image and Bson Document. The delete method will successfully (seemingly) remove them; the document, the fs.files entry, and the fs.chunks entry.

However, when the entry is deleted and then proceeds to upload the new image, only the fs.files entry and the BsonDocument will be pushed to the server. The actual image is left off.

I'm running MongoDB 3.2.6 for Windows.

The replace block followed by the upload block

```
if (newMD5.Equals(oldMD5) == false)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Updating image " + fileWithExt);

    BsonValue targetId = docCollection.FindOne(Query.EQ("id", fileNoExt))["_id"];
    deleteImageEntry(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(targetId.ToString())));

    //continues to upload replacement
} else
{
    continue;
}                     
}

//create new entry 
uploadInfo = mongoFileSystem.Upload(memStream, fileFs);                    

BsonDocument entry = new BsonDocument();
entry.Add("fileId", uploadInfo.Id);
entry.Add("id", fileNoExt);      
entry.Add("filename", fileFs);
entry.Add("user", "");

//appends to image collection
var newItemInfo = docCollection.Save(entry);
```

And the delete method

```
    public static bool deleteImageEntry(IMongoQuery query)
{
    MongoInterface mongo = new MongoInterface();

    try
    {
        var docCollection = mongo.Database.GetCollection("employees");
        var imageCollection = mongo.Database.GetCollection<EmployeeImage>("employees");

         var toDelete = docCollection.FindOne(query);               
         BsonValue fileId = toDelete.GetValue("fileId");

        mongo.Gridfs.DeleteById(fileId);
        WriteConcernResult wresult = imageCollection.Remove(query);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Image could not be deleted \n\r" + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Sorry the code is messy, I've doing a lot a guerrilla testing to try and find a reason for this. Similar code has worked in other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. After a few more hours of debugging it turned out to be the MD5.ComputerHash() function was setting the memStream iterator to the end, and so there was no data being uploaded. Using memStream.Position = 0; solved the problem.